# Architecture: MVC based web-apps around a REST interface

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, rest, jakarta-ee

I'm not sure how to phrase my question....

From different sources I pick up the idea that it makes sense to build **web applications around a REST interface**.  A REST service could execute some controller logic (validations, database-access, etc) and then return a (static) *.xhtml resource.  Combined with a decent javascript framework, this html page could complete itself by issuing the approriate AJAX calls.

Intuitively I see value in this (it feels more lightweight than a server-side document model like in JSF), but I also feel like I'm missing the complete picture here.  What 'they' are referring to, is that simply Struts or Spring MVC with a REST sauce?

Do you see what I mean?  Can somebody put these idea's in perspective?  Point to **a resource that explains the approach** I'm trying to grasp?  What are the roots?

Thank you for helping me to clarify all this! J.

Answer (score 0):

Names coined in this context are [SOFEA](http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=47213) and [SOUI](http://www.appcelerant.com/mvc_is_dead.html).